# jquery stop infinite animation on mouseout

Tags: jquery

I have 4 divs that fade in indefinitely based on mouseover of another div, this is all fine. However i would like the animation to stop on the mouseout but this doesn't seem to work.

```js
$("#live").mouseover(function() {
  fadeloop('#live-step1', 100, 200, true);
  fadeloop('#live-step2', 100, 200, true)
  fadeloop('#live-step3', 100, 200, true);
  fadeloop('#live-step4', 100, 200, true);
});

$("#liveMusic").mouseout(function() {
  fadeloop('#live-step1', 100, 200, false);
  fadeloop('#live-step2', 100, 200, false);
  fadeloop('#live-step3', 100, 200, false);
  fadeloop('#live-step4', 100, 200, false);
});

function fadeloop(el, timeout, timein, loop) {
  var $el = $(el),
    intId, fn = function() {
      $el.fadeOut(timeout).fadeIn(timein);
    };
  fn();
  if (loop) {
    intId = setInterval(fn, timeout + timein + 100);
    return intId;
  } else {
    clearInterval(intId);
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:550px;width:550px;">
  <div id="live" style="width:50px;height:50px;;background-color:gray">hover</div>
  <div id="live-step1" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#ffffff">step1</div>
  <div id="live-step2" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#ffffff">step2</div>
  <div id="live-step3" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#ffffff">step2</div>
  <div id="live-step4" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#ffffff">step4</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uosww7bm/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to the UI, it's far more preferable to use CSS where possible. As such, you can achieve this using a keyframe animation along with the `:hover` pseudo selector. This gives you the 'pause on mouseout' behaviour by default.

Also note that you should remove the inline styles and place them in an external stylesheet, something like this:

```css
@keyframes fadeAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

body { background-color: #EEE; }

.container {
  height: 550px;
  width: 550px;
}

.container div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.container #live {
  background-color: gray;
}

.container #live:hover ~ div {
  animation: fadeAnimation .4s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="live">hover</div>
  <div>step1</div>
  <div>step2</div>
  <div>step2</div>
  <div>step4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have now implemented it using pure css and thus i have to accept this as the correct answer! although both answers seem to work for me

Comment: Glad to help. They will both work, but as I mentioned CSS is by far the better choice - it's a better separation of concerns, and performs better as it's hardware accelerated

Comment: Thank you Rory I cannot find a css reference to the "~" symbol towards the end: 

.container #live:hover ~ div {
 ...
}

Can you point me to a references so i can understand its significance?

Comment: Sure, it's the [General Sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

I can see couple of errors in your code:

- why are you using two different selectors to trigger the event: on mouse over is #live, for the mouseout is #liveMusic (which I cannot see in the snippet).
- secondly, you call fn() outside the if/else condition, so it will be continuously called even though you are clearing the timeout.

I've updated your snippet, using only one div, but result would be the same even with the others.

```
    $("#live").mouseover(function() {
  fadeloop('#live-step1', 100, 200, true);
});

$("#live").mouseout(function() {
  fadeloop('#live-step1', 100, 200, false);
});
var intId;
function fadeloop(el, timeout, timein, loop) {

  var $el = $(el),
     fn = function() {
      $el.fadeOut(timeout).fadeIn(timein);
    };
  if (loop) {
    intId = setInterval(fn, timeout + timein + 100);
  } else {
    clearInterval(intId);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Check it out here [updatedFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uosww7bm/3/)

Comment: hi sissy the liveMusic naming issue was my mistake when i was adding it to fiddler. as for your seccond point spot on! thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Sissy i tried to use your improved answer and somehow this only works ok for the one div, when you add more divs it gets confused and falls in an infinite loop again...https://jsfiddle.net/uosww7bm/6/

Comment: yes i've seen the problem and actually i didn't have much time to try to solve it... but i read you're using the css solution, so if i will have some time later i will try to fix it ;)